# Diode fails open

Tags: diodes

[image: Schematics of figure 1-36]

The question asked is the following: [image: image of question being asked]

The book says that the correct answers are: \$V_{limit}\$ = 0V, \$V_{diode}\$ = 5V.

I don't get why it ended up like that. My intuition says that, "fails <s>to</s> open" means not functioning, and so no forward current flowing in the diode. In that case, the voltage across the resistor is 10V and the voltage across the diode is 0V.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No current is right, because your circuit is interrupted, and you need a closed circuit to get current flowing.

[image]

And when there's no current through the resistor there won't be a voltage drop across it neither, per Ohm's Law: Voltage = Current x Resistance. So 0 V across the resistor means the full 10 V is across the diode (not 5 V!).

If the diode would fail *shorted*, there wouldn't be a voltage drop across the diode, and the full 10 V would be across the resistor, giving (again due to Ohm) 10 V/ 1 kΩ = 10 mA.

Comment: hmm, im like confuse, we know theres no current in the resistor right, ohms law says 0v. but when we look at it, the left portion of the resistor is exposed to a higher potential, and the right is of a different one, so a potential must exist? correct me if im wrong

Comment: Can't possibly be 5V for the Vdiode. Where did the other 5V go?

Comment: @Martin - You don't have to complain about this with me, I didn't say anything about 5V! :-)

Comment: @stevenvh yeah ur right, i just realized im wrong. sorry

Comment: @stevenvh so correct me if im wrong in this explanation, since theres no current flowing in the resistor, the resistor itself acts as part of the conducting wire, and so it is an ideal wire whose resistance is zero (no voltage drop), but the resistor has 1k ohm, so the 1k ohm is disregarded/irrelevant as long as there is no current flowing. so overall, it can be viewed as nothing, but part of the wire? is that correct?

Comment: @blackandyello - No, the resistor doesn't become a wire, it remains at 1k. But take a resistor laying on you table: it doesn't have a current through it, so if you measure the voltage it will be zero (where would the voltage suddenly come from???). Still the resistor is 1k. This is a constant for that resistor and per Ohm's Law defines the voltage for a given current: 0 mA x 1000 ohm = 0 V.

Comment: Ok, so what if we add another resistor on the other side of the voltage source, will thrre be an effect to the voltage across the diode?

Comment: @blackandyello - In series with it? Still no current, so no voltage drop. Since the diode forms an interruption you don't have a closed circuit, and you need a closed circuit to have current flowing. So as long as the interruption is there, no matter how many resistors you add, there won't be any current through them, and thus 0 V across each of them.

Comment: Ok, but howcome that across the diode, a potential difference is establish??? So does that mean, if i add another resistor whose resistance is 10 googleion ohms, the voltage across the failed diode remains the same? Isnt it theres a limit to the reaistance we add?

Comment: When you said the diode "fails open" you mean it becomes an open circuit, by definition an infinite resistance. As long as that approximation holds, it doesn't matter how much finite resistance you add to the resistive part, there won't be any current flow through the resistors, so no voltage drop across them. ...

Comment: However, in the real world, the failed diode might only be 1 Megohm or something...then if you add a comparable resistance to the resistive arm, and if you have a meter with a low enough leakage not to disturb the circuit, you could measure some drop across the resistors and a lower voltage across the (failed) diode.

Comment: @blackandyello - 0 mA x whatever resistance = 0 V. Let's take the largest known number, Graham's Number, so large that nobody really knows *how* large it is. Well, the 0 mA x GN ohm = 0 V. There's no way around it. You don't have current because your circuit isn't closed, then you never have any voltage drop across any resistor, then the remaining voltage is 10 V, and that's across the defective diode.

Comment: @ThePhoton - "1 Megohm or something...". Don't complicate things now! :-) Not in my backyard! ;-)

Answer (score 9):

"Fails open" is not fail to open. "Fails open" means that it blows up and becomes an open circuit, so in this case there would be the full 10V across its terminals, with 0V across the limit resistor. I don't see how anyone can get 5V.

If it "failed to open" it would presumably remain as a working diode with 0.7V or so across it because it is forward biased.

Answer (score 7):

You did not read carefully. The problem states "fails open" (== failed, the failure mode being *permanent open*), not "failed TO open" as you seem to have read (and which happens to mean the exact opposite!)

Comment: You ARE a C programmer, aren't you? == instead of =?

Comment: C++, Python, C, Jal, ...

Answer (score 3):

I think you're wondering the question every student has come to wonder whenever the expected answer doesn't line up with the book's answer:

> Is the textbook wrong or is my answer wrong?

The answer here is ***YES***, the textbook answer is wrong.  The only way to get 5V across the diode would be if it failed and turned into a 1k resistor.  The answers (assuming the book meant what it said when it said the diode `fails open` are:

> \$V_{limit}\$ = 0 V, \$V_{diode}\$ = 10 V

Both sides of the resistor will be at the same potential since no current is flowing through it, and if the diode has failed open, the potential across it will be the potential of the resistor (10V).